# PHP: How do I decode the given String using PHP in Array

Tags: php, json

Response String:

```
jQuery21408111137825120874_1451285646793({"result":"error","msg":"0 - This email address looks fake or invalid. Please enter a real email address."})
```

This response is given by an API. I am using PHP at my end.I am not sure that given response is in JSON, but I have tired with json_decode but not success. Please help me how do I decode it in an Array format.

Comment: Which API are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use 
    $encodeArr = json_decode($yourString, true);

youll get an array as a result..

or u can use 
    $encodeArr = json_decode($yourString);
    $msg=$encodeArr->msg; 
this will also work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string = 'jQuery21408111137825120874_1451285646793({"result":"error","msg":"0 - This email address looks fake or invalid. Please enter a real email address."})';

preg_match('#\(({.*?})\)#', $string, $match); // this will return the value inside the {}
$yourString = $match[1];
$encodeArr = json_decode($yourString);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($encodeArr);
```

**Result is (in object format):**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => error
    [msg] => 0 - This email address looks fake or invalid. Please enter a real email address.
)
```

If you want to convert this object into an `array` than use this before print:

```
$requiredArr = (array) $encodeArr;
print_r($encodeArr);
```

**Result for this is:**

```
Array
(
    [result] => error
    [msg] => 0 - This email address looks fake or invalid. Please enter a real email address.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the second argument of json_decode PHP function is for transform json to array PHP. If it's a valid json you can have a array PHP object otherwise your json is invalidate.

View : [json_decode PHP function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php)